# Main email address for "Contact Us" in settings is not changing

Tags: emails, plugin-contactform

we have a contact section on our website which is going to an info@ email address.  I need to change this to my email.  I have gone to Globals - Settings - Email address and changed it there, but when I sent a test email it didn't work.  Could you please tell me if I need to try a different section?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the popular 'Contact Form' plugin, try Settings > Contact Form (under Plugins heading) and the field you want is the first field, 'To Email'.

The variables in Globals are 100% custom but usually change the email address that is displayed sitewide such as in your footer or contact page. They can be, but are not necessarily, wired into your contact form.

If you can't see Settings in the left side nav, or the Plugins section in Settings, you may need to request greater permissions from your CMS admin.

Be gentle (mods), this is my first answer in a long time ;)

Comment: Might be your first answer in a long time, but you get an upvote from me!

Comment: thanks so much, i appreciate the reply!